# Is this a valid retopology method?

Tags: topology

[image: d]

I have here two similar meshes. Top is criss-crossed with edge loops and this is usually how I go about it.

But then I decided to minimize the tris by deleting the "needless" vertices resulting in the one below. Which looks weird to me.
This was an attempt in retopology and optimization which sacrifices the edge loop flow.

In one BlenderGuru video he cuts off an edge loop like this, flowing it into another vertex. That's where I got the idea but I'm not sure if I managed to follow it correctly, that's where the confusion came about.

My question is. Was this the correct way to go about it? Or should I stop trying to pass high-poly objects as low-poly and focus on doing low-poly designs?

I know that edge flow is important in animations and rendering performance and I wouldn't have done this if this was a human face or body. So my main concern is doing solid objects.

Comment: Hello :). This is one of those old old questions. Are n-gons good or bad? There is no definitive right or wrong answer, even between pros. Gleb Alexandrov has a [very comprehensive video on it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjnCV2PIkKA), concerning hard-surface modeling, like your example.

Comment: Because they don't disrupt the clean interpolation of normals on divisions of curved surfaces, ngons in bounded flat surfaces are absolutely fine, IMO.

Comment: I'll be sure to check the video out. I know about the whole debate but my concern is primarily on the number of tris generated for render or gaming. I'm willing to sacrifice "some" visual if the processing return is much greater.  @Robin, That's where I was going with this "retopo".